# Discrepancy between goal completions and event totals - server-side tracking Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm using [universal-analytics](https://github.com/peaksandpies/universal-analytics) to set up subscriptions tracking on the server-side of our application. By looking at event totals the numbers are correct (comparing to actual subscriptions). The issue comes when I try to set up a goal for a specific event. The goal completions are way less than the total events.

```js
const ua = require("universal-analytics");

class Visitor extends ua.Visitor {
    setUser(user) {
        this.set("uid", String(user._id));
        if (user.ipAddress) {
            this.set("uip", user.ipAddress);
        }

        if (user.userAgent) {
            this.set("ua", user.userAgent);
        }
    }

    purchaseSubscription(user, purchaseType, newPlan, oldPlan, inTrial, revenue) {
        this.setUser(user);
        let label = `${newPlan} - ${inTrial ? "Trial" : "Out of Trial"}`;
        if (oldPlan) {
            label = `${newPlan} - ${oldPlan}`;
        }
        this.event("Purchase a subscription", purchaseType, label, Math.round(revenue));
        this.send();
    }
}

module.exports = new Visitor(process.env.GA_KEY);
module.exports.Visitor = Visitor;
```

Here is the goals data

[image: Here is the goals data]

Here is the event totals data

[image: Here is the event totals data]

And here is the goal setup

[image: And here is the goal setup]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add the code instead of screenshots in the question.

Comment: @Sateesh Thanks just added it :)